# Excel filter hide result with VBA filter criteria

Tags: excel, vba, filter, autofilter

I apply a date filter with VBA to an excel table but the result are not showed.

```
    Public Dte As Date
Dte = "31/12/2020"
With Sheets("Temptable").ListObjects("Temp").Range
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=package
    .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<" & Dte
End With
```

field 2 is working but not field 4: it hide the cells like there are no value. Then I go to excel filter and clic on "date filter" -> "Before" -> Dte is there -> I press enter, and it apply the filter.
Why it does not apply automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

Try writing it like below, you're missing quotes around package, so I believe VBA is trying to filter based on a variable "package" that wasn't made. Using `Option Explicit` could catch these types of errors in the future, as it forces you to define any variable you invoke. However without all your code, I figure whatever is in the second column of your table contains the text "package" and that it wasn't a variable you were using elsewhere.

```
    Public Dte As Date
Dte = "31/12/2020"
With Sheets("Temptable").ListObjects("Temp").Range
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="package"
    .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<" & Dte
End With
```

Comment: Great! You did it i was finding to sort it out. The mistake was hide itself :P @Mark S.

Comment: Awesome! I was at first focused on the date, but noticed it was applying correctly, so when I checked what the other filter was I saw it was blank and immediately knew what was happening. Hopefully the OP will accept this answer, but I'm not 100% if that's how they're underlying data worked. I only recreated what I could picture from the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all reply. In fact package is already a variable that is set in the code i didn't mention, and it does filter the correct string data.

Your soltuion doesnt fix the problem unfortunately. even with the below :

```
        Public Dte As Date
Dte = "31/12/2020"
With Sheets("Temptable").ListObjects("Temp").Range
    .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<" & Dte
End With
```